# Getting Authorized User Details Using Twitter API using PHP Laravel

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, sttwitterapi

I could able to generate authorization URL and could able to trigger my callback API.

But how can I get the authorized user details such as first name, last name, id, profile pic etc?

I didnt find any solution on internet and I almost spent a lot of time on this.

Please help me to find out a solution.

I got these

```
{"oauth_token":"PVHUBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","oauth_verifier":"5vlkG3xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

I want to get the firstName,lastName and profile pic of this account using these keys.

Pease help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json end point using postman and provide your app credential and authorized user credentials with auth 1.0